# get-aduser with MYDOMAIN\myuser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am using powershell to get information about remote desktop published apps. I need to get information about assigned users to a published app.  When I use Get-RDRemoteApp, it returns the assigned users in the format MYDOMAIN\myuser.  I need call Get-ADUser on this user information, but I can't get Get-ADUser to work with that format.

How can I call Get-ADUser with the username information MYDOMAIN\myuser?

```
$remoteapps = Get-RDRemoteApp -ConnectionBroker $connectionBroker -CollectionName $collectionName
foreach ($app in $remoteapps) {
    if ($app.FilePath -notlike '*\QBLaunch.exe') {
        #Write-Host ($app | Format-List | Out-String)
        foreach ($userName in $app.UserGroups) {
            # the following fails because userName is MYDOMAIN\myuser
            $user = Get-ADUser $userName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$userName.Split('\')[1]` maybe?

Comment: Use the Identity property.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps